# Chaos monkey scenarios that can be tested for Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, monkey-testing, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am using chaos monkey implementation of [code centric](https://codecentric.github.io/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/) to test a spring boot application which is hosted in a non scaled environment (i.e It is not hosted on cloud). Below are the scenarios that I am testing. Kindly advice if I can test any more scenarios

1. Latency Assault
2. Exception Assault
3. Kill Application Assault
4. Memory Assault

Answer (score 0):

A few that I can think of -

1. Disk space Assault
2. CPU Assault
3. Time/Clock Assault

You can look for more ideas on other platforms such as [Gremlin](https://help.gremlin.com/attack-params-ref/) or [Chaos Toolkit]ץ(https://docs.chaostoolkit.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Chaos Monkey for Spring Boot does not support any more assault types besides the ones you listed. Chaos Engineering however features more levels of experiments: People, Processes, Practices, Application (where you can use Chaos Monkey for Spring Boot), Platform and Infrastructure.

Platform could be Kubernetes. Attacks on the platform level can be attacks like removing a node from the cluster and so forth. Infrastructure level features attacks on the host level (fill memory using tools like `stress`, cause data loss with tools like `tc`)

Possible attacks can be:

- Device failures
- cpu failures
- database failures
- internet failures (dns, isp, internet routes)
- time bombs (memory leaks, counter wrap round)
- date bombs (leap year, leap second, epoch)
- retry storms, cascading overload, cascading failures

more of these attack types can be found in the excellent presentation of Adrian Cockroft: https://www.youtube.com/embed/cefJd2v037U